# Evaluate $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+k}}$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to compute the following limit:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+k}}$$

Using Squeeze Theorem suggests two candidates: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, using fact that $\frac{n}{\sqrt{2n}}\le\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+k}}$, and 1, using fact that $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+k}}\le\frac{n}{\sqrt{n}}$, but I cannot find upper bound confirming $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ not a lower bound confirming 1. I don't know many tools yet (in particular we haven't touch any derivatives material yet), which suggests I should look for better bounds, but after trying this for a while, I still fail. I would be grateful for any tips.

Comment: Hint: Riemann sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Try using Squeeze theorem on $$\frac1{\sqrt{n+k-1}+\sqrt{n+k}}=\sqrt{n+k}-\sqrt{n+k-1}>\frac1{2\sqrt{n+k}}>\frac1{\sqrt{n+k}+\sqrt{n+k+1}}=\sqrt{n+k+1}-\sqrt{n+k}$$

Comment: Good one! Any intuition on how did you come up with that? Seems kinda magical.

Comment: @qiubit When dealing with square roots common trick is to multiply by the conjugate, and because here you can't do it and no other trick seems plausible it would be logical to try to somehow adjust it that you can multiply by the conjugate. But apart from that it's mostly magic :)

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+k}} &=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n \sqrt{1+\frac k n}} \\
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{ \sqrt{1+\frac k n}}\right) \frac 1n \\
&= \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}} \mathrm dx \\
\end{align}

Comment: I wrote that material in my class didn't touch any derivatives, so I'm not allowed to use integrals too.

Comment: @qiubit OK. I'll try to solve without that. But you should **explicitly mention that in the main body of your question.**

Comment: @JaideepKhare: be fair! If the OP hasn't done derivatives (as was stated), then it's unlikely they'll have done integrals.

Comment: @RobArthan I said that because when I studied limits, (before derivatives, of course) our teacher told us about this method to evaluate using integrals. (We had knowledge of integrals as we had already studied basics of it in Physics).

Answer (score 1):

Yet another solution:

Let $G(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt k}$. Then by [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{G(n)}{\sqrt n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{G(n)-G(n-1)}{\sqrt n-\sqrt{n-1}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt n+\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt n}=2$$

Then your sum is:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{G(2n)-G(n)}{\sqrt n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{G(2n)}{\sqrt n}-\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{G(n)}{\sqrt n}=2(\sqrt 2-1)$$